# How to select records as columns in SQL

Tags: sql

I have two tables: tblSizes and tblColors. tblColors has columns called ColorName, ColorPrice and SizeID. There is one size to multiple colors. I need to write a query to select the size and all the colors (as columns) for a that size with the price of each size in its respective column.

The colors must be returned as columns, for instance:

```
SizeID : Width : Height : Red : Green : Blue  
1---------220-----220----£15----£20-----£29
```

Hope this makes sense
Thank you

Edit: Tried the following code but not quite sure what's wrong:

```
DECLARE @Colors NVARCHAR(4000), @Query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Colors = ''

SELECT @Colors = @Colors + '[' + C.Color +'],'
FROM tblTempProductSizesColors SC
INNER JOIN tblColors C on SC.ColorID=C.ID
GROUP BY Color
ORDER BY Color

SET @Colors = LEFT(@Colors,LEN(@Colors)-1)


SET @Query = '
SELECT *
FROM (  SELECT TS.Sizeid, TS.Width, TS.Height, TS.Depth, TC.Price
        FROM tblTempProductSizes TS
        INNER JOIN tblTempProductSizesColors TC
        ON TS.SizeId = TC.SizeId INNER JOIN tblColors C on TC.ColorID=C.ID) A
        PIVOT(SUM(Price) FOR C.Color IN ('+@Colors+')) AS PT'

EXEC sp_executesql @Query
```

Comment: Why can't you query the database, then pivot the results to the format that you want?

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Comment: @OrangeDog - I'm not entirely sure how to use Pivot in SQL, just looking into it now, thank you.

Comment: @Leigh - I didn't mean in SQL, I meant in the system that is sending the queries.

Comment: Sorry I'm using MS SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: @Leigh Its MSSQL 2005+?, so you can use `PIVOT`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to write every color, and the expression for those columns, you can use Dynamic SQL if you have MSSQL 2005+ (first, be sure of take a look to this [link](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)).
**UPDATED following comment**

```
DECLARE @Colors NVARCHAR(4000), @Query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Colors = ''

SELECT @Colors = @Colors + '[' + C.Color +'],'
FROM tblTempProductSizesColors SC
INNER JOIN tblColors C on SC.ColorID=C.ID
GROUP BY Color
ORDER BY Color

SET @Colors = LEFT(@Colors,LEN(@Colors)-1)


SET @Query = '
SELECT *
FROM (  SELECT TS.Sizeid, TS.Width, TS.Height, TS.Depth, TC.Price, C.Color
        FROM tblTempProductSizes TS
        INNER JOIN tblTempProductSizesColors TC
        ON TS.SizeId = TC.SizeId INNER JOIN tblColors C on TC.ColorID=C.ID) A
        PIVOT(SUM(Price) FOR Color IN ('+@Colors+')) AS PT'

EXEC sp_executesql @Query
```

Comment: Lamak, thank you for writing this up. It looks like it should work but.. When I asked the question I tried t simplify my problem rather than explaining the entire thing in detail. There's actually three tables. I've tried to mod your code to fit but not quite sure where things have gone wrong. I've posted in my above question your modified code.

Comment: @Leigh I updated my answer modifying your code, so I think you should try again and tell me if it works.

Comment: Lamak you absolute legend! Thank you so much for helping me with this, your code works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

```
select s.Sizeid, s.Width, s.Height, 
Red = SUM(CASE WHEN c.ColorName = "Red" THEN c.ColorPrice ELSE 0 END),
Blue = SUM(CASE WHEN c.ColorName = "Blue" THEN c.ColorPrice ELSE 0 END),
Green = SUM(CASE WHEN c.ColorName = "Green" THEN c.ColorPrice ELSE 0 END)
from tblSizes s
join tblColors c on c.SizeId = s.SizeId
group by s.Sizeid, s.Width, s.Height
```

Comment: Thank you John. Thats exactly what I need - but.. I would have to type out every color in the query, and I would get a column for every color. Is this the only way?

Comment: @Leigh: I think that is the only way in vanilla SQL, are you using a DB server which supports `PIVOT` e.g. SQL Server?

Comment: This will probably be much slower than fetching the data and pivoting it yourself.

Comment: This won't be slow at all -- but I agree that pivoting the data in code is probably the right solution.

Comment: @Leigh: I really can't imagine a situation where you would want a variable record type coming back depending on which colors happen to be present so I don't see you're having to know all the colors in advance is a true issue.  You'll need to know that anyway unless you are going to process these results in code and then I would question why you are pivoting in the SQL in the first place.

Comment: Well when the data is entered the user adds dynamic columns (colors) to a pricing grid, for which they can specify a price in said color. I expect only those columns the user checked when entering the data to be returned upon calling the data back so I can display it the same way. It's not a massive issue that I have to add all colors in the query myself, but it does become and issue when more colors are added to the DB. I then need to modify this query accordingly - every time. V grateful of your help. Thank you